# CSS and JS files for external theme not working in magento

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, css, external

I installed **magento 2** and the **luma theme** works fine but on installing an external theme(multi stores by netbase), the page only loaded the header and complained about not being about not being able to load a `style-m.min.css` resource.

I have tried all means, cleared cache,removed static folder, merged css and js files, I still got the same result.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Please First deploy your website,Did you generate and deploy static content using command line.

You can regenerate your static content by using following command :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```